# Стэк не работает

Tags: c++, стек

Хотелось бы вывести 4 3 2 1 0. Но ничего не выводит. Где я свернул не туда?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct number {
    int x;
    number *adr;
};

void add(number *,int);
void show(number *);

int main() {
    number *top = new number;
    top = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        add(top, i);
    }
    show(top);
    system("pause");
}

void add(number *top, int x){
    number *temp = new number; 
    temp->adr = top;
    temp->x = x;
    top = temp;
}

void show(number *top) 
{
    number *temp = top; 
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        cout << temp->x << " "; 
        temp = temp->adr; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Учитесь самостоятельно дебажить. Поставьте точку останова на вход `main()` и пройдите по шагам, контролируя значения переменных, таким образом найдете где и что не так. Навык такой работы не менее важен, чем собственно написание кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `add` не модифицирует и не может модифицировать указатель `top` в функции `main`, ибо он передается в функцию `add` *по значению*. Указатель `top` в `main` навсегда остается равным null-указателю. Поэтому ничего и не выводится.

Либо передавайте `top` в `add` *по ссылке*, либо выработайте какой-то другой способ возвращения нового значения `top` из `add` в `main`.

---

Отдельно стоит заметить, что последовательность

```
number *top = new number;
top = NULL;
```

бессмысленна и только порождает утечку памяти. Зачем вам понадобился этот `new`?